# How to determine the number of bytes from a string with mix of "\x" and normal characters?

Tags: encoding, ruby, binary-code

I was looking at [this exercise](https://www.pentesterlab.com/exercises/ecb/course) and it was mentioned that the string `\x1AL\xD23k\xCA\x1D\xD7` consists of 8 bytes. However, I fail to see how there are 8 bytes in the string. Shouldn't there be 7 bytes instead since `\x1A` would represent 1 byte and any character without `\x` is a byte on its own?

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a security question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\x1A`,`L`,`\xD2`,`3`,`k`,`\xCA`,`\x1D`,`\xD7`. 8 bytes.

The convention is that `\x` is followed by exactly two characters base 16 that together denote the byte value. You might want to check out [C escape sequeces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences).